# Hide Recursive Relationships on Graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database that has recursive and non-recursive relationships. I would like to hide the recursive relationships from the graph. When I query the database, the table shows the correct information but the graph still displays the relationship. Is there a simple way to hide this?

Query/db information:

Structure: (node1:Type1)-[rel:Relationship]-(node2:Type1)

Sometimes node1 and node2 are the same node (recursion) and other times not. I would like to hide the recursion on a graph and show only when nodes 1 & 2 are different.

What I've tried: 
$MATCH (node1:Type1)-[rel:Relationship]-(node2:Type1) WHERE node1.name <> node2.name RETURN node1, node2

This gives the correct table of information but the incorrect graph.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The duplicate question answer result is not showing in my neo4j dashboard (toggle button). However, the problem was solved by detaching/deleting the relationships I was uninterested in, which may provide a solution to others with a similar problem.